# Redirect URL containing #!

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a Rewrite Rule that helps me redirect a page with no hindrance.

I am rewriting

```
mydomain.com/best
```

to

```
mydomain.com/#!/
```

using

```
RewriteRule ^\/best\/? /#!/ [R=301,NE,L]
```

Now I want to Rewrite

```
mydomain.com/#!/best
```

to

```
mydomain.com/#!/
```

using the same rule but it does not work and goes directly to

```
mydomain.com/#!/best
```

how can I solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)/?$
RewriteRule ^ /%1/best/ [NE,L,R]
```

Comment: I need /#!/best redirected to /#!/ 

Looks like your solution is doing the opposite to that.

Comment: Yes, sorry I misunderstood the question, FYI ,nothing after the # is sent to the server, You cant do this redirection using htaccess, try javascript client side redirection.

Comment: http://example.com/#! will load the same page without redirecting, because Server doesnt receive # and charecters after it in Uri